# how to access assets/images from the view in Sails.js?

Tags: html, ejs, sails.js

I simply want to add an image in a view in my Sails-Project

My view-file has the location

```
views/album/albums.ejs
```

and the image is located in

```
assets/images/placeholder.png
```

if I add the image like this

```
<img src="../../assets/images/placeholder.png">
```

I get this error

```
GET    http://localhost:1337/assets/images/placeholder.png    404 (Not Found)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sails use Grunt (Gruntfile.js in root of project) to execute some tasks during sails lift. One of that tasks is to copy files from assets directory to .tmp/public/ directory (in development version). So if u add your file to assets directory you will need to restart sails (sails lift) to get it accessible from .tmp/public/ (what is public accessible directory root). Also its important to note that if u put files directly to .tmp/public/ it will be accessible instant, but on next sails lift it will be deleted, since one of Grunt tasks is to clear that directory before copy new files. All of this u can find on sails documentation ([assets](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/assets) and [asset-management](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/asset-management)) and by reading Gruntfile.js in root of your project

Comment: What if there are thousands of images? How to make sails access the image directly?

Comment: @yongho This way you are accessing images directly. So you access image like this <img src="/images/my-image.png" />. But what is important to note is that you store your images inside 'assets' directory and during lift process Sails will copy them to you public directory. That is all. But once when images (or other assets) are copied to public directory, you access them with direct url. Also Sails keep same directory structure like you create inside 'assets' directory.

Answer (score 8):

```
<img src="/images/placeholder.png">
```

should work. the assets folder is the equivalent to adding a folder with the static middleware in express.

[asset documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/assets.md)

Comment: You'd think so: *"Upon lifting, a file called myApp/assets/newFolder/data.txt could be accessed at http://localhost:1337/newFolder/data.txt"*, but this simply is wrong information -- even though it is on the docs site (docs.anatomy.assets). I can't believe they would have this bs on there.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have `grunt` hook removed.

When removing the grunt hook you must also specify the following in `.sailsrc` in order for your assets to be served, otherwise all assets will return a **404**.

```
{
  "paths": {
    "public": "assets"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.
In sails version 0.12.0,
I was trying to show an image from assets folder to homepage.ejs.
Then by using below img tag, it solved my problem.

```
<img src="/images/placeholder.png" width="30px" height="30px">
```

But as your ejs file is inside views/album/albums.ejs

I may suggest, below may work

```
<img src="../images/placeholder.png" width="30px" height="30px">
```

But the right approach in sails ejs pages is,

```
<img src="/images/placeholder.png" width="30px" height="30px">
```

This must work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *tasks/sync.js* file in your project, add the following object in `files` array:

```
{
        cwd: './assets/images',
        src: ['**/*.*'],
        dest: '.tmp/public/images'
}
```

you need to have sails-hook-grunt and grunt-sync installed.