# Run a static images on sails.js

Tags: static, routes, sails.js

I would like to view a static image of my sails project.

I save in /assets/images/dependent/photos an image and I don't know how to render this image with an url.

How I can route this??

Thank you

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786136/how-to-access-assets-images-from-the-view-in-sails-js/18799604 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

1. Create file `express.js` in `config/`
2. Write this in the file:

   ```
   module.exports.express = {
     customMiddleware: function(app){
     app.use('/images', require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express').static('./assets/images/dependent/photos'));
    }
   }
   ```
3. Access your files like this:

   ```
   yourdomain.com/images/yourimage.png
   ```